# Google Drive Connection With PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

When i connect the php file with google drive, i got following error:

C:\Users\mysys\workspace>php quickstart.php

Fatal error: Class 'Google_DriveService' not found in C:\Users\mysys\workspace\quickstart.php on line 12

Call Stack:
    0.0000     237560   1. {main}() C:\Users\mysys\workspace\quickstar
t.php:0

Note: i did all operation in the following link:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

Comment: Do you have google-api-php-client library in the same folder as your quick start.php scrip?

Comment: yes. i have both it in the wamp www folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your path `C:\Users\mysys\w orkspace\quickstart.php` is bad. You have extra white space between w and o.